# SSH Connections to Server Freezes

Tags: networking, server, ssh, freeze, openvpn

I have a server that has SSH enabled. It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
The connection to the SSH server sometimes freezes, and when it does anyone else connected to it when it freezes for me reports that it also freezes for them. Sometimes, after about 10-50 seconds, it'll unfreeze and "act" normal again. This has become a common problem and was wondering what could be causing it?
If you guys need logs or anything I'll be happy to provide them.
Also, if this might help, I did recently install OpenVPN on the machine, though this machine is new so OpenVPN was installed along with it. Not for sure if that could also be causing the issue.

---

`syslog`:

```
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode NetworkManager[1047]: <info>  [1548903470.3868] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode dbus-daemon[1000]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=1047 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode whoopsie[1324]: [21:57:50] offline
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode dbus-daemon[1000]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Jan 30 21:57:50 staff-libraryofcode nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Jan 30 21:57:51 staff-libraryofcode whoopsie[1324]: [21:57:51] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan 30 22:00:47 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan 30 22:00:47 staff-libraryofcode anacron[11097]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-01-30
Jan 30 22:00:47 staff-libraryofcode anacron[11097]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode NetworkManager[1047]: <info>  [1548904070.6125] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode dbus-daemon[1000]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=1047 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode whoopsie[1324]: [22:07:50] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode whoopsie[1324]: [22:07:50] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode whoopsie[1324]: [22:07:50] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode dbus-daemon[1000]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Jan 30 22:07:50 staff-libraryofcode nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Jan 30 22:07:51 staff-libraryofcode whoopsie[1324]: [22:07:51] online
Jan 30 22:17:01 staff-libraryofcode CRON[11198]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Stopped target Default.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Stopped target Paths.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[10305]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 11212 (kill).
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Jan 30 22:18:26 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of matthew.
Jan 30 22:58:02 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of matthew.
Jan 30 22:58:02 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Started Session 19 of user matthew.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Reached target Timers.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Started Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Reached target Paths.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Reached target Sockets.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Reached target Basic System.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Reached target Default.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[11425]: Startup finished in 157ms.
Jan 30 22:58:03 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Jan 30 22:58:10 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Started Session 21 of user matthew.
Jan 30 22:58:38 staff-libraryofcode systemd[1]: Started Session 22 of user matthew.
```

---

This also does appear to happen when connected to OpenVPN or the PPTP VPN. The connection freezes for a short period of time, like we have no connection to the server anymore and can't access any websites. And after 10-50 seconds everything just "magically" starts working again.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue in ubuntu server 16.04 LTS, all putty windows will freeze as soon as I run "openvpn --config file.ovpn" and the server stops responding to ssh connections, except in my case I have to reset the server, did you reach any conclusions regarding the cause?

Comment: I was, but I don't know if it'd be beneficial to you. I use Hyper-V for my machine and removing Network-Manager and doing static IP config in the interfaces for me worked.